# Automate events A11y in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup

In the latest [Svelte version](https://svelte.dev/blog/whats-new-in-svelte-november-2022) they have added new accessibility warnings.

the doubt I have is that I would like to automate it on build so I don't have to constantly write the `onkeyDown` event as in the example

```html
<div on:click="{() => {clickEvent1()}}" on:keyDown="{() => {clickEvent1()}}" />
<div on:click="{() => {clickEvent2()}}" on:keyDown="{() => {clickEvent2()}}" />
<div on:click="{() => {clickEvent3()}}" on:keyDown="{() => {clickEvent3()}}" />
```

Any rollup package or Svelte option that automates it?

Comment: (`on:keyDown` would not do anything, DOM events are - with rare exceptions - fully lowercase => `on:keydown` ...which still does nothing unless the element or a descendant is keyboard focusable & focused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

You are not supposed to add `click` events on `div` or other non-interactive elements. Things that are clickable should be in a `button`, which can be styled however you want (can even be made to only show the contents).

Comment: sometimes we need to add click on div..  so what that solution ? 
or how can I stop this warning.

Comment: @HNazmulHassan: You should make the same action available via keyboard. Just adding key event handlers will often ***not achieve this***, the element or one of the children has be focusable for such events to fire. Then you can add a comment `<!-- svelte-ignore [warning name here] -->` to remove any false positive warnings, the full list of warnings is [here](https://svelte.dev/docs/accessibility-warnings#a11y-click-events-have-key-events), the compiler should also output the warning name. It should be extremely rare that click events are added on anything non-interactive.